# Store files of awk output in a different folder

Tags: windows, awk

I wish to store the output file in a different folder. 
Here is my code:

```
BEGIN{
    RS = "\n"
    originalFile= ARGV[1]   
    name="_MySQl.sql"
    file=substr(originalFile,1,length(originalFile)-4)
    path = "C:\\Users\\sanjanaj\\Desktop\\CheckScript\\ConvertedDDL\\"
    filename = path file name
    }
    {

    //logic
    print $record > filename

    }
```

Then I got this when I tried to run it on Windows CMD.

```
C:\Users\sanjanaj\Desktop\CheckScript>awk -f test.awk REF_CALENDAR.sql
awk: test.awk:24: (FILENAME=REF_CALENDAR.sql FNR=4) fatal: can't redirect to `C:\Users\sanjanaj\Desktop\CheckScript\ConvertedDDL\REF_CALENDAR_MySQl.sql' (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: and you have created `C:\Users\sanjanaj\Desktop\CheckScript\ConvertedDD` before running this command? The error message seems to indicate that you haven't. Redirection only works with files in dirs that exist. It won't make a non-existent path for you. Does `dir C:\Users\sanjanaj\Desktop\CheckScript\ConvertedDD` work? Good luck.

Comment: Thanks worked :)